Blazor Server: How to share data between component and controllers?
From a component I am navigating to an external OAuth2 endpoint that is performing an Authorization Code Flow and then redirects back to my application. The redirection is handled via a dedicated controller. I am now trying to get the authorization code received in the controller into the rest of the application (ideally via services). Since components and controllers run in a different scope I cannot simply inject the scoped service - it will result in a new instance. I wonder what's the best practice to share data between components and controllers? In general, cross-scope communication in Blazor Server seems to be rather tricky and I cannot find much information about it whatsoever.

Have you thought of adding a Singleton service  - Create a singleton service that stores the authorization code. Since a singleton is shared across the application, both your Blazor components and your controller can access and modify this service. But there is Caveat - Ensure thread safety when multiple users are interacting with the service, as Blazor Server is a multi-user environment.

@Sohan I didn't think about a singleton service yet, I could probably just have one with a global event that I subscribe to on the component. Good idea.

@Ivde0 Another approach I had earlier was having InMemorySession storage where If the authorization code only needs to be stored temporarily and is tied to a session, you can use session storage. We can use ASP.NET Core's session state to store the authorization code. This can then be accessed from both your controller and Blazor components. But for this  You need to enable session management in your application and make sure that session state is properly configured.
If you want i can try to have sample code for same

@Sohan Isn't storing sensitive info in local or session storage dangerous due to XSS?

@Ived0 We can store the session on Backend and retrieve only we needed? Something like
HttpContext.Session.SetString("AuthToken", token);  and  then In your Blazor components, retrieve the token from the server when needed, without storing it client-side.

@Sohan I opted for a singleton service now that sends a global event "AuthCodeReceived" event. Seems to work fine.

The easiest way is to use cookie. In the controller you could operate cookie by
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("mycode", "xxx");

In the blazor component you could get the cookie by using "js interop" when interactive mode/ using "httpcontext" when prerender(SSR)
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime js

@code

//the script could be wrap in to js file and reference in App.razor
<script>
    function WriteCookie(name, value, days) {
        var expires;
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else {
            expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function ReadCookie(name) {
        console.log("test");
        const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
        const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
        if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }
</script>

@code{
    string code;
    [CascadingParameter]
    HttpContext? httpContext{ get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
        if (httpContext != null)
        {
            code = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("ReadCookie","mycode");
        }
        else
        {
            code = httpContext.Request.Cookies["mycode"];
        }
    }
}


Based on above discussion - I am adding sample code to inject and use the Singleton service for sharing authorization code between controller and blazor componenet
Your Auth Service
public class OAuthService
{
    public string AuthorizationCode { get; set; }
}

Register this service as a singleton in Starter class for eg . Program.cs
services.AddSingleton<OAuthService>();

Now, in your controller, you can set the authorization code:
   public class OAuthController : Controller
   {
    private readonly OAuthService _oauthService;

    public OAuthController(OAuthService oauthService)
    {
        _oauthService = oauthService;
    }

    public IActionResult Callback(string code)
    {
        _oauthService.AuthorizationCode = code;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

In your Blazor component, you can access it like this:
@inject OAuthService OAuthService

<p>Authorization Code: @OAuthService.AuthorizationCode</p>


This wouldn't work with multiple users.

You need to handle the and ensure thread saftey when working with multiple users. lock can be used when interacting with multiple users
